# useState not updating array correctly

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, use-state

I am working on carousel slider. In which i use 2 arrays. 1 array 'slideData' of objects which contain images and id's and the other array 'slideNum' contain indexs to iterate. slideArr is the final array which we will map, it contain images from 'slideData' and map according to 'slideNum' indexes. When i update 'slideArr' array with useState than is not updating but when i update directly using array.splice than its working.

```js
const SecondGrid = () => {

  const len = SlideData.length - 1;
  const [first, setFirst] = useState(1);
  const [second, setSecond] = useState(2);
  const [third, setThird] = useState(3);
  let [slideNum, setSlideNum] = useState([0, 1, 2]);
  const [slideArr, setSlideArr] = useState([
    {
      id: 0,
      imgsrc: "./assets/c1.jpg",
      data: "Here is Light salty chineese touch",
    },
    {
      id: 1,
      imgsrc: "./assets/c2.jpg",
      data: "Try our special breakfast",
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      imgsrc: "./assets/c3.jpg",
      data: "Taste the italian likalu food",
    },
  ]);

  const next = () => {
    setFirst(first >= len ? 0 : (prevState) => prevState + 1);
    setSecond(second >= len ? 0 : (prevState) => prevState + 1);
    setThird(third >= len ? 0 : (prevState) => prevState + 1);

   // const arr = [...slideArr];

  // storing next index image into all three Cards
    slideNum.forEach((val, key1) => {
      SlideData.forEach((value, key) => {
        if (key === val) {
          slideArr.splice(key1, 1, value);
          
          // this is not working
          
          // arr[key1] = value;
          // console.log(arr);
          // setSlideArr(arr);
          
          //console.log(slideArr);
        }
      });
    });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    next();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setTimeout(() => {
    //updaing slideNum number,in which 'first' contain id of image which will be on 0 index, its updating through useState.
    
      setSlideNum([first, second, third]);
      next();
    }, 3000);
    return () => clearTimeout(interval);
  }, [first, second, third]);


  return (
    <Container>
      <div className="row">
        <div className="d-flex flex-wrap justify-content-around ">
          {slideArr.map((val) => (
            <SlideCard val={val} />
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    </Container>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful to have some standalone code that demonstrates the problem but just looking at the commented out bit you say is not working, you can use `map()` to change values in an array:

```javascript
setSlideArr(slideArr.map(item => (item.id === 1 ? value : item)))
```

Here's a demo [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/69019012-o5rdf?file=/src/App.js).

Also, your `console.log(slideArr)` should be in a `useEffect` hook if you want to see the state value after it has changed.

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know, what happens is that you can't splice slideArr because it's useState, what you would be better off doing is:

```
if (key === val) {
      var arr = slideArr;
      arr.splice(key1, 1, value);
      setSlideArr(arr);
}
```

Comment: This still mutates state. `arr = slideArr` does not make a copy of the array, but instead just points `arr` to the same reference as `slideArr`.